# AsyncImageView oncomplete resize

Tags: objective-c, ios

May I know any way to resize a image after get from url using `AsyncImageView`? This is the code that I have till now:

```
NSLog(@"image x:%f y:%f", _imageView.frame.origin.x, _imageView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"image w:%f h:%f", _imageView.frame.size.width, _imageView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"image w:%f h:%f", _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);


_imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"];


//cancel loading previous image for cell
[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:_imageView];

//load the image
_imageView.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[AppSetting getPkParkingPhotoPath],[_data objectForKey:@"photo"]]];

_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

NSLog(@"image x:%f y:%f", _imageView.frame.origin.x, _imageView.frame.origin.y);
NSLog(@"image w:%f h:%f", _imageView.image.size.width, _imageView.image.size.height);
```

I want to get the real dimension of the image and resize & fit to width and dynamic height.
how can I delegate the `onComplete` method of `AsyncImageView`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

Comment: But how to get the dimension? As I know, I just can get the width and height after loaded the photo...but can I use any onComplete method to do that?